# Filename of graph .meta in a TensorFlow checkpoint directory

Tags: tensorflow

How do I get the filename of the latest checkpoint's graph?

In the examples for `tf.train.import_meta_graph` I typically see the filename hard-coded to be something like checkpoint_dir + 'model.ckpt-1234.meta'.

After importing, `.restore` can load the latest training parameters as in:

```
saver.restore(*session*, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(*my_dir*))
```

However, what is a reliable way to get the graph's filename?  In my case,

```
tf.train_import_meta_data(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(*my_dir*) + '.meta')
```

should do the job but I don't think its reliable as checkpoints don't necessarily save the metagraph every time, correct?

I can write a routine that looks through the checkpoint dir and walks back until I find a .meta.  But, is there a better/built-in way such as `tf.train.latest_metagraph(*my_dir*)`?

Answer (score 0):

I just found an article where someone implemented the routine I mentioned in my question.  This isn't an "answer", but is what I'll use assuming there isn't a built-in solution.

This is from the very nice article at [seaandsalor](http://www.seaandsailor.com/tensorflow-checkpointing.html/) written by João Felipe Santos.

I don't know the usage rules, so I didn't want to directly link to his code.  Follow that link if interested and then go to the gist mentioned on the bottom.